# Monitor plug socket remote from desktop PC

Tags: remote-access, ac-power

Planning a one off party event that involves turning mains lights on/off and then playing media on a PC connected screen.

It need not be very fast and doesn't need to use internet but WiFi is available if that route would be simpler/cheaper.

It is easy enough to source dump [433mhz remote controlled sockets](https://www.wilko.com/en-uk/wilko-remote-control-wall-plug-sockets/p/0343066)
and rig the remote to fire when needed. But I am unsure how to go about detecting the transmission from remote to the socket to play the media on the PC.

I imagine I would need some sort of USB transceiver but I haven't found any USB ones that I could drive under Linux. Most of the articles online use expansion boards for Pi or Arduino. I did find one [article](https://www.cnx-software.com/2017/05/23/this-8-usb-transceiver-can-add-433-mhz-device-support-to-your-home-automation-gateway/) using a cheap USB dongle and others vaguely mentioning USB SDR radio.

I do have a [USB to TTL Serial Converter](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B072K3Z3TL/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) that I use for flashing, could I buy a 433 transceiver and rig it up to that?

Alternatively I have a Wiimote lying around that could be rig up as the sensor and then use a WiFi plug that is accessible from Linux to turn on/off the lights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have internet, it would be easiest to use a switch that can be controlled via IFTTT. Just google IFTTT light switch and you'll see the light !
If you dont have internet, you can still use a RaspberryPI with a relay shield and run an MQTT broker on a PC to which the raspberryPI will connect. And you can then run another MQTT program on the PC to send on/off messages to the PI. You could also locate the broker on the PI.
May also run a web server on the PI. Google can help there too !

Comment: Thank-you - Going to use my mobile phone as a MQTT broker (Arch ARM has a package for mosquito)